# print directly datatable values

Tags: vb.net, linq

Good evening to everyone!
I have a datatable with 5 columns.records are about train groups reservations.:

| DEPARTURE | ARRIVAL | LEVEL | CAR/COACH | PNR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| roma | milano | 1. | 2. | xxxyx |
| roma | bologna | 1. | 3. | xxxyx |
| firenze | milano | 1. | 3. | xxxyx |
| bologna | milano | 1. | 2. | xxxyx |
| roma | firenze | 2 | 8. | xxxyx |
| firenze | bologna | 2. | 5. | xxxyx |
| firenze | milano | 3. | 6. | xxxyx |
| roma | milano | 1. | 2. | xxxyx |

then i have a form in which the user should choose record to print BASED on a combobox selection (station):
how many people are loading in Roma,
how many people are in 1st class
how many people are in car 2
etc.

having an output like this:

train 9999

roma

154 loaded

132 unloaded

32 passenger in 1st class

30 passenger in 2nd class

23 passenger in car 1

8 passenger in car 2

1 passenger in car 3

10 passenger in car 6

i use linq to popoluate listboxes with these records in different forms,but to allow user to print these information how can i do ?
thanks for your help.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're just asking how to print out a `ListBox` to a printer?

Comment: no,i want to print out records without showing them : the print form has 5 checkbox.print people per level,print total passengers,print total passenger per car,etc.depending on checkboxes i should print more information.the point is the record must be filtered with a combobox value (station).linq should be fine but, how can i put the filter?

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like `Where` is what you are looking for.

Comment: well i dont' know how to do it ,at all.I used a where when i display records.but i don't know how to print them .probably sort them,fill an invisible datagridview and then print it would be the best solution ?